# GetCommandLineArgs is not returning what I expected

Tags: c#

I recently started studying C# through the book and I came to this example where I'm trying to print out arguments passed from the command prompt:

```
namespace SimpleCSharpApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] theArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

            foreach(string arg in theArgs)
                Console.WriteLine("Arg: {0}", arg);
        }
    }
}
```

My command prompt **input** looks like this:

*D:\...\SimpleCSharpApp\bin\Debug>SimpleCSharpApp.exe arg1 arg2*

And the **output** looks like this:

Arg: SimpleCSharpApp.exe

Arg: arg1

Arg: arg2

What I supposed it would look like is:

Arg: arg1

Arg: arg2

My question is, why does it recognize my execution command as a member of string arguments? What am I supposed to change to get the output I expected?

I could just change foreach loop into for loop starting from the 2nd element like this:

```
namespace SimpleCSharpApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] theArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

            for (int i = 1; i < theArgs.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Arg: {0}", theArgs[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not resolve my curiosity, can I somehow make it not to record executable file like an argument and print it out with foreach loop to get the output I expected?

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) behaviour

> **The first element in the array contains the file name of the executing program.** If the file name is not available, the first element is equal to String.Empty. The remaining elements contain any additional tokens entered on the command line.

If you want to skip First argument use [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method.

```
 foreach(string arg in theArgs.Skip(1))
            Console.WriteLine("Arg: {0}", arg);
```

Comment: Exactly! I will choose this as the best answer the moment SO allows me, thanks once again! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the args passed to main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(string arg in args)
            Console.WriteLine("Arg: {0}", arg);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know, that's what I've learned before this example, but I wanted to know how to do it this way. Thanks!